# How to collapse all the nested collapsible-set and collapsible elements in nested collapsible set?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

How to collapse all the nested collapsible-set and collapsible elements in nested collapsible set in Jquery Mobile?

Below is the code in the JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ycP8y/

```
<body>
<div data-role="content">
    <div data-role="collapsible-set">
        <div data-role="collapsible">
             <h1>
                <div class="ui-btn-up-c ui-btn-corner-all custom-count-pos">47</div>
                Test</h1>

            <div data-role="collapsible-set">
                <div data-role="collapsible">
                     <h1>
                        <div class="ui-btn-up-c ui-btn-corner-all custom-count-pos">47</div>
                        Test</h1>

                    <div data-role="collapsible-set">
                        <div data-role="collapsible">
                             <h1>
                                <div class="ui-btn-up-c ui-btn-corner-all custom-count-pos">47</div>
                                Test</h1>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using jQM 1.2 as in your fiddle, you can just call trigger("collapse") on all collapsibles (http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.1/docs/content/content-collapsible-methods.html ):

```
$(document).on("pageinit",  function(){
    $("#btnCollapse").on("click", function(){
        $("[data-role=collapsible]").trigger("collapse");
    });
});
```

> Updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/ycP8y/2/)**

Comment: Thank you for information. What if I need to invoke this on the click of collapsible, and not in additional button. I updated the fiddle to provide you more interface.

Comment: Are you wanting to collapse all child collapsibles when a parent is collapsed so that next time you expand there are no children expanded? If so, use the collapse event (http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.1/docs/content/content-collapsible-events.html) of the collapsible widget and then trigger the collapse on all children collapsibles: $(this).find('[data-role=collapsible]').trigger("collapse")